Is Trace operation commutative when weighted by a positive semidefinite matrix?
The commutativity of Trace operation is often discussed to be a consequence of the matrix product. One writes
$$tr(AB) = tr(BA) \qquad (1)$$
Now consider the situation where given a positive semidefinite matrix $\mu$, one can interpret $tr(\mu AB)$ as an inner product see Theorem $1$ here.
My question: With this new "weighted" Trace, under which even Cauchy-Schwartz inequality holds, but  does the commutative property also hold, i.e. can we write
$$tr(\mu AB) = tr(\mu BA)?$$

A simpler counterexample:
$$\mu = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Then $\text{tr}(\mu AB) = 1 \neq 0 = \text{tr}(\mu BA)$.

In fact, for any matrix $\mu$, $\text{tr}(\mu AB) = \text{tr}(\mu BA)$ for all $A, B$ iff $\mu$ is a scalar matrix (i.e., $\mu = c1$ for some scalar $c$). This follows from noting any matrix is a linear combination of projection matrices, so a linear functional is determined by its value on projections. But any two rank-one projections $P, Q$ are connected in that there exists $A$ s.t. $P = AA^\dagger$ and $Q = A^\dagger A$. So $\text{tr}(\mu P) = \text{tr}(\mu Q)$. This means there is a fixed number $c$ s.t. $\text{tr}(\mu P) = c$ for any rank-one projection $P$. Rank-one projections span all projections, whence they also span all matrices, so as $\text{tr}(\mu P) = c = \text{tr}(c1 \cdot P)$ for rank-one projection $P$, we must have $\text{tr}(\mu A) = \text{tr}(c1 \cdot A)$ for any matrix $A$. In particular,
$$\text{tr}((\mu - c1)(\mu - c1)^\dagger) = \text{tr}(\mu (\mu - c1)^\dagger) - \text{tr}(c1 \cdot (\mu - c1)^\dagger) = 0$$
So $\mu - c1 = 0$, i.e., $\mu = c1$.

By the way, this condition you called “commutative property” is more commonly called “tracial”. Tracial linear functionals are quite important in the classification and study of $C^\ast$-algebras and von Neumann algebras.

If $\operatorname{tr}(\mu AB)=\operatorname{tr}(\mu BA)$ for all $A$ and $B$, then $\operatorname{tr}(\mu[A,B])=0$. Since the set of all commutators is precisely the set of all traceless matrices, $\mu$ in turn is orthogonal (with respect to Frobenius inner product) to the subspace of all traceless matrices, whose codimension is $1$. Hence $\mu=cI$ for some scalar $c$. As $\mu$ is positive semidefinite, $c$ must be nonnegative.

It doesn't hold. A counterexample:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9 \end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}2&3&4\\5&6&7\\8&9&10 \end{pmatrix},\mu=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Firstly, $\mu$ is positively semidefinite.
$tr(\mu AB)=36+192+0=228$. However, $tr(\mu BA)=42+192+0=234$.
Thus, the equality doesn't hold.
Note that one reason why it doesn't hold is that the diagonal entries of $AB$ is $36,96,174$, for $BA$ is $42,96,168$. So the LHS of the equation in the question is $1\times36+2\times96\neq1\times42+2\times96=RHS$.

Thanks, @math... How about this: Since $\mu$ is positive semidefinite, we can write $\mu = P^\dagger P$. Then $tr(\mu AB) = tr(P^\dagger P AB) = tr(P AB P^\dagger) = \sum_k <e_k|P AB P^\dagger |e_k> = \sum_k <f_k| AB | f_k > = tr_{f}(AB)$ where $tr_f$ is the trace w.r.t. basis ${ f_k = P^\dagger e_k }$. Should it not be true that now $tr_{f}(AB) = tr_{f}(BA)$?  I am using Dirac's bra-ket notation $<|>$.

@Mike $\text{tr}(A) = \sum_k \langle f_k|A|f_k\rangle$ only when ${f_k}$ is an orthonormal basis. ${f_k = P^\dagger e_k}$ is only an orthonormal basis when $P^\dagger$ is a unitary, in which case $\mu = P^\dagger P = I$.

Thanks @DavidGao. That clears my doubt. Any insights on why does the Cauchy Schwartz inequality hold in such a form $|tr(\mu A^* B)|^2 \le tr(\mu A^*A) tr(\mu B^*B)$ even when $P$ is not unitary?

@Mike Cauchy-Schwarz holds for all positive semidefinite inner product, i.e., whenever $\langle \cdot | \cdot \rangle$ satisfies it is conjugate-linear in the first variable, linear in the second variable, and $\langle a | a \rangle \geq 0$ for all $a$, then Cauchy-Schwarz holds. $\langle A|B \rangle = \text{tr}(\mu A^\ast B)$ satisfies the above conditions if $\mu$ is positive semidefinite.

@Mike If you are thinking of the conjugate-symmetry condition in inner products, that actually follows from $\langle a|a \rangle \geq 0$ by polarization identity (in the complex case, at least, in the real case you still need to prove it independently). Though in this specific case you can just directly show it if you want as well:$$\text{tr}(\mu A^\ast B) = \overline{\text{tr}((\mu A^\ast B)^\ast)} = \overline{\text{tr}(B^\ast A\mu)} = \overline{\text{tr}(\mu B^\ast A)}$$
